# running selenium chrome browser in docker container

Tags: selenium, docker, docker-compose, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use selenium chrome driver with docker. Unfortunately I can't get it working. When I do docker-compose up to launch the container it crashes with a

```
"container_name exited with code 1" error.
```

Using docker logs -t -f I was able to get the below error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: 
Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
```

I know that there have been other stack overflow posts about this issue, but all the solutions involve adding chrome options. I have already tried adding various chrome driver options without any luck. See code below.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=socks5://localhost:9050')
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized') 
options.add_argument('window-size=1200x800')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, desired_capabilities=caps)
```

I have tried various combinations of the above code with no luck. I also tried commenting out the 'proxy=server' option and running the container, but I get the same error. When I run the normal python code it works without any errors.

Below is the relevant portion of my  Dockerfile.

```
# Extra suff chrome driver needs
RUN apt-get install -y libglib2.0-0=2.50.3-2 \
libnss3=2:3.26.2-1.1+deb9u1 \
libgconf-2-4=3.2.6-4+b1 \
libfontconfig1=2.11.0-6.7+b1

# need this for chrome driver, not just ui 
RUN apt-get install -y wget xvfb unzip

# Set up the Chrome PPA
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list

# Update the package list and install chrome
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

# Set up Chromedriver Environment variables
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION 2.19
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_DIR /chromedriver
RUN mkdir $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR

# Download and install Chromedriver
RUN wget -q --continue -P $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR "http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip"
RUN unzip $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR/chromedriver* -d $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR

# Put Chromedriver into the PATH
ENV PATH $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR:$PATH
```

Comment: Just throwing this out as I'm not sure it's the cause: You're doing a apt-get google-chrome-stable which I'm assuming will download the latest chrome browser. However you're specifically using ChromeDriver v2.19, which is a really old version. Are we looking at a compatibility mismatch between the chromedriver and chrome browser being used?

Comment: That was the issue thanks ! I wasted hours and hours on this. Using ChromeDriver 2.46 instead of 2.19 fixed it.

Comment: turn your comment into an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Great to hear that it works!!! :-) Have done up a proper answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're facing an incompatibility between the chromedriver and chrome browser versions being used.

Here are the two lines in question:

`RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable`

The above means that you'll download the latest chrome browser.

`ENV CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION 2.19`

However, over here you're specifically using ChromeDriver v2.19, which is a really old version.

You'll need to use compatible versions, which can generally be found in the release notes:
http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads